# Postgres won't listen on Docker host IP address after reboot until Postgres is restarted

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a brand-new Debian 9 with Docker 18.09 (installed from the official Docker repository) and Postgres 9.6. I've edited `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` to set the `listen_addresses` parameter:

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1'
```

After making that change and restarting Postgres, my Docker containers can connect to Postgres at 172.17.0.1 without any problems. The issue comes when I restart the entire OS, Postgres will not listen on 172.17.0.1 until I restart Postgres itself. I've swapped the order of the addresses in `postgresql.conf` to no avail, running `show listen_addresses;` in `psql` *says* it's listening on both the ports I've specified, but `sudo netstat -na` shows it listening only at 127.0.0.1:

```
$ sudo netstat -na
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

A restart of Postgres (`systemctl restart postgres`), and now it's also listening on 172.17.0.1:

```
$ sudo netstat -na
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

This means that my Docker containers that start on boot that connect to Postgres fail to start up automatically because they get a "Connection refused" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing a bunch more testing, I realised that it seems to be a timing issue around Docker and Postgres starting, I'm guessing something like the Docker interface doesn't come up until Docker itself has started or something and thus Postgres can't listen on it because it doesn't exist yet.

### 2023 update

It turns out there's a far better way of doing this by way of systemd "drop-in units" as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211674/178979):

Create the directory `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service.d` and inside create a `docker.conf` file with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Wants=docker.service
After=docker.service
```

This accomplishes the same thing in the original answer except it leaves the system-installed unit file alone.

### Original answer

I copied `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service` (yes, with the `@` in it) to `/etc/systemd/system/` and in the `[Unit]` section set it to start only *after* Docker has started:

```
[Unit]
...
After=docker.service
```

Then configured my custom units that start the Docker containers to start only after Postgres (rather than Docker, since Postgres won't start until after Docker anyway):

```
[Unit]
...
Wants=postgresql.service
```

And now everything works as expected!